# clickable drop down in table header with tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

```
  $('#table').tablesorter({
         headers: {1: {sorter: false}}
  });

<table id='table'>
     <tr>
       <th>col 1</th>
       <th><select id='something'>
             <option value='1'>1</option>
             <option value='2'>2</option>
          </select>
       </th> 
       <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the above code does not allow me to click on the select dropdown and make a selection.  how can i achieve this?

Comment: user onchage event see my ans

Answer (score 0):

its simple, use change event..

```
$(function(){
        $('#something').on('change', function() {
          console.log( this.value );
        })
    });
```

Full replicated Working Code..

```
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id='table'>
     <tr>
       <th>col 1</th>
       <th><select id='something'>
             <option value='1'>1</option>
             <option value='2'>2</option>
          </select>
       </th> 
       <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
</table>

    <script>
        $(function(){
             $('#table').tablesorter({
         headers: {1: {sorter: false}}
  });
            $('#something').on('change', function() {
              alert( this.value );
            })
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: clicking on the dropdown does not present the options.  the click is interpreted by tablesorter.

Comment: try updating your tablesorter plugin, I've replicated your code with latest tablesorter. Its working see my edit for full code

Comment: what version of tablesorter you using?

Comment: don't know, they have not given version, I just downloaded it

Comment: with latest download your code does the same thing.  Your code is also missing thead attributes.

Comment: I know but, I just took your code, didn't add anything rather than change event. Probably you would like to post your full code ...

Comment: even using what you posted does not work for me the way it does for you.  Im guessing there is something else going on. let me look around.